# Issue with Azure AD B2C oauth/OpenIdConnect

Tags: azure, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I have an odd issue with azure authentication. It works in one scenario (logging in with an angular app using adal) but not in an other (loading the asp.net web api up and logging in via the swagger ui authorise mechanism). I have narrowed it down to a post to the:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/{tenantid}/oauth2/authresp
```

endpoint which rather unhelpfully returns:

```
302

<html>
 <head>
  <title>Object moved</title></head>
  <body>
   <h2>Object moved to <a href="http://localhost:49919/swagger/ui/oauth2redirect-html#error=server_error&amp;error_description=AADB2C%3a+An+exception+has+occured.%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+1816d2f8-aa74-4433-a7c0-d9c8fabebdb0%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2017-10-27+13%3a46%3a08Z%0d%0a&amp;state={ommitted}">here</a>.</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically telling me an exception has occurred.

error_description = AADB2C An exception has occured.

CorrelationID = 1816d2f8-aa74-4433-a7c0-d9c8fabebdb0

Timestamp = 2017-10-27 13:46:08

The angular app, does exactly the same post but that however returns a link with the token id:

```
302

<html>
  <head>
   <title>Object moved</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <h2>Object moved to <a href="http://localhost:4200/#state={state -
   ommitted}&amp;id_token={id token - omitted}">here</a>.
    </h2>
   </body>
 </html>
```

I can't see any differences in the posts. This one does not work (initiated from swagger ui on web api project)

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/{tenant - omitted}/oauth2/authresp HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1595
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.62 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
DNT: 1
Referer: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant - omitted}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={clientid - omitted}&redirect_uri=https:%2f%2flogin.microsoftonline.com%2fte%2f{tenant - omitted}%2foauth2%2fauthresp&response_type=id_token&response_mode=form_post&nonce={nonce}&state=StateProperties
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,de-CH;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,fr-CH;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5,it-CH;q=0.4,it;q=0.3
Cookie: {cookie - omitted}=; x-ms-gateway-slice=005; stsservicecookie=cpim_te

id_token={omitted}
```

But this post does:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/{tenant - omitted}/oauth2/authresp HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1590
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.62 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
DNT: 1
Referer: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant - omitted}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={clientid - omitted}&redirect_uri=https:%2f%2flogin.microsoftonline.com%2fte%2f{tenant - omitted}%2foauth2%2fauthresp&response_type=id_token&response_mode=form_post&nonce={nonce}&state=StateProperties
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,de-CH;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,fr-CH;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5,it-CH;q=0.4,it;q=0.3
Cookie: {cookie - omitted}; x-ms-gateway-slice=003; stsservicecookie=cpim_te

id_token={omitted}
```

As the posts are pretty much identical the issue must lie somewhere in either the cookie or the id token (which I cannot supply for security reasons). Pasting the ID tokens from both requests into http://www.jwt.io gives me same information with the correct claims present in both. So I am a little stuck and hoping someone from the azure team can step in and help?

Many thanks

Comment: Do you have a page or request URL that you can share for both cases? If not, can you get the request URL from a fiddler request and provide for both cases even if it's targeting localhost?

Comment: Yes I can provide the full requests from fiddler but I cannot post them here as they contain sensitive information

Comment: @OmerIqbal I have added you on LinkedIn, if you could message me we can sort out how to get these requests to you. Thanks

Comment: Sure, I'll try to get in touch there,  but the entire fiddler request is not necessary, only the request url which is  public. You can strip out any pii if needed. That'll allow others to see it too.

Comment: @OmerIqbal Are you referring to the url in the post (i.e. the one that contains the tenant id?)

Comment: @OmerIqbal I can provide you with some URL's so you can replicate the issue if you wish?

Comment: Hi Magrangs, yes, please do provide the original request URLs to the authorize endpoint and token endpoint. That will allow us to validate any potential gotchas. Can you also create two requests in Fiddler and compare them on your local box and see the differences? That will give a clue as to what is going on.

Comment: @OmerIqbal Please contact on me linkedIn and I can get the url's over to you. I have done exactly that (compare the requests in fiddler) and the outcome was what I posted in the question itself. A have issued a contact request so if you could respond there that would be great. Thanks

Comment: Hi Mangrangs, I tried getting in touch with you but can't find you on LinkedIn. This is my profile: https://www.linkedin.com/in/omeriqbal0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the referrer in your request samples, it looks like you're not calling /v2.0/ B2C endpoint. For example, in the following request, the path should be /{tenant}/oauth2/**v2.0**/authorize...

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={clientid}&redirect_uri=https:%2f%2flogin.microsoftonline.com%2fte%2f{tenant}%2foauth2%2fauthresp&response_type=id_token&response_mode=form_post&nonce={nonce}&state=StateProperties
```

Due to this, you're getting unexpected behavior across both your apps. This also means that the applications you are using were not created using B2C portal (we verified this via our offline chat as well).

As of now, B2C ONLY supports applications created through the B2C portal. So, if you can kindly create an application through the B2C portal, and try again, you should have this issue resolved.

Comment: When we first created the app registrations they were created on the v1 endpoint. The trick to this was to create the app on the b2c portal as described by Omer. You can then use the 'try it now' buttons to see the url's that you should be calling.

Comment: Also make sure your web api config uses the v2.0 policy endpoint. i.e. https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p={1} (where 0 is your tenant and 1 is your policy)